# Keep Python script running after screen lock (Win. 7)

Tags: python, windows

I am running a Python script that uses the `requests` library to get data from a service.

The script takes a while to finish and I am currently running it locally on my Windows 7 laptop. If I lock my screen and leave, will the script continue to run (for ~3 hours) without Windows disconnecting from the internet or halting any processes? The power settings are already set up to keep the laptop from sleeping.

If it will eventually halt anything, how do I keep this from happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As long as the computer doesn't get put to sleep, your process should continue to run.

Comment: This is correct. I do this (on Win 7) on a daily basis. You can walk away from the computer or lock it and the scripts continue to execute. If you are seeing otherwise then we have a terminology disagreement and you are not encountering locking but perhaps sleep mode or shutdown?

Comment: Yes python script keeps running when Windows device is locked and haven't went to sleep. I have verified on my Windows 11 laptop so it must be True for Windows 10, 8, and 7 as well.

Answer (score 7):

Check "Power Options" in the Control panel. You don't need to worry about the screen locking or turning off as these wont affect running processes. However, if your system is set to sleep after a set amount of time you may need to change this to Never. Keep in mind there are separate settings depending on whether or not the system is plugged in.